# FreeBSD undo uppercase characters in username

Tags: truenas, user-accounts

I set up a FreeNAS box a while ago and against better judgement, used an uppercase character when creating my username. This has led to a directory called `George`.

Now, when I later read that uppercase characters were highly discouraged, especially in the use of Samba (which I'm using), I decided I'd like to try and repair this.

What steps should I take to rename a user account from mixed uppercase to all lowercase, bearing in mind that data already exists for this user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Edit the username, groupname and home path in the passwd file with `vipw`
- Edit the groupname in the group file with `vipw -g`
- Rename your homefolder with `mv`
- Reboot the server

Comment: ...and next time trust your better judgment :-) (Really, most users can't remember which are the upper-case letters in their passwords. Letting users have upper-case letters in their usernames just doubles the chance for mistakes.)

Comment: `vipw` did the job for the user, but I had to change the case in `/etc/group` too.

Comment: @deed02392: You are right. I forgot about that. I edited the answer.

Comment: And what a beautiful edit it was. Cheers.

Comment: You also want to rename the user in /etc/aliases

Comment: So I tried this with FreeNAS v11 and it doesn't work at all. Users that are renamed with vipw are reverted after the next reboot.

Comment: FreeNAS is a bit strange with it's configs. If recall correctly, most of the config files are recreated on boot from some database. I don't know for sure and I don't know how it works exactly. FreeNAS is so heavily modified, that I wouldn't call it a FreeBSD.